# Implementing 2fa in two steps

Tags: authentication, authorization, theory, one-time-password, two-factor-authentication

I did a lot of research on *how to implement 2fa* on my app.
My app will enforce every user to use 2fa (I will use OTP).

I think that in my app, (because every user will need to use 2fa, and I will use only OTP), I can have only 2 steps:

1. Log in the user providing username, password and OTP.
2. If step 1 is successful, authentication is done.

From all the sources I found, the 2fa steps are always the same:

1. log in the user providing username and password.
2. If step 1 is successful, ask the user for the OTP token.
3. If step 2 is successful, authentication is done.

In my head, if I have optional 2fa, or 2fa using SMS/email, then I must have the step in the middle (authenticate the user, send the SMS/email and wait for the code), but with OTP, I already have the code and I can provide it in the same login form with the username and the password.

I haven't seen this kind of 2fa with only 2 steps, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Both of your examples are the same.
In the First scenario, the server is waiting for the user to enter OTP and the same process follows in the second scenario.

These are distinct steps in 2FA authentication

1. The user sends their username and password to the server to be authenticated as usual
2. The server confirms the credentials are correct and asks for a second input from the user.
3. In this case it’s a one-time passcode (OTP)
4. The user provides the OTP, and the server finally authenticates the user

[2FA](https://auth0.com/learn/two-factor-authentication)

Comment: Of course they are not the same, in the first scenario, the user sends the username, password and OTP token in the same request. The backend validates the 3 inputs at the same time. On the second scenario, in the first request are sent only the username and the password, the backend gives success response, and is waiting for another request with the otp token. Your answer is in my question ...

Comment: How does user get OTP in the first scenario?

Comment: There is no self registration for the users in the app, the superusers creates the user and the user receives email with verification code. After the verification link is clicked, the user needs to set a password and receives the QR code for the OTP. So this mean that the user will have a valid password and will have OTP that  can be used to sign in.

Answer (score -1):

## How To Enable Github ( 2FA ) two-factor authentication

### First Install Mobile App "Authy"

You must read QrCode generated by Github Setting Two-factor-authentication by using app "Authy" to obtain the 6 Digit **Verify Code**.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.authy.authy
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/authy/id494168017

### Second Follow Steps Using App Authy :

1. Register new account at Authy by using your real device phone.
2. You will see message asking to verify your email address, now enter your current email that have been used at your Github account. The link for activate your email will be sent to your mail.
3. Open App Authy From Mobile, Click add account scan the QrCode found at github setting 2FA, the Authy app will provide 6 digit numbers
4. After enter code 6 digit at your github setting download the "github-recovery-code".
5. Congratulation Now Your Verify Your Acction